# homotopy between constant simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Assume that $K,L$ are constant simplicial sets (i.e all the faces maps and the degenerancies maps are equal to the identity and $K_{i}=K_{0}$, $L_{i}=L_{0}$ for $i>0$). Assume that there is a simplicial homotopy between two maps $f,g\: : \: K\to L$. Then is $f=g$?

Comment: Intuitively, you can ask the same question about maps between discrete spaces. Is is true in that case? Why? Now translate that into simplicial language. Hint: The zero simplices are the "points" of the discrete space.

Comment: Ok, if I apply the geometric realization functor to $K$ and $L$ I should obtain two discrete topological spaces. Thus the question is: two maps between discrete topological spaces are homotopic only if they are equal...the answer should be yes right?

Comment: You only need the codomain to be discrete for this to be true.